# How to properly eager load column parameter in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my tornado webapp, I use SQLAlchemy, and I'm trying to eagerly load an Object, without much success.

My object structure looks something  like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   username = db.Column(
     db.String(20),
     nullable=False,
   )
   is_enabled = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
   password_hash = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(130), nullable=False)
   memberships = db.relationship('Membership',
                                 back_populates='member')


class Company(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
   website = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
   address = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
   memberships = db.relationship('Membership',
                                 back_populates='company')


class Membership(db.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
   company_id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                               db.ForeignKey('company.id'))
   role = db.Column(db.String, default='REGULAR_USER')
   member = db.relationship("User", back_populates="memberships")
   company = db.relationship('Company', back_populates="memberships")
```

I'm fetching the User object like this:

```
user_q = self.application.db.query(User).filter(User.id == request.user_id)
user_q.options(undefer('*'), joinedload('*'))
fetched_user = user_q.one_or_none()
```

And then I store this object into an ExpiringDict. For the request that sets this object, everything is ok, but for subsequent requests I get errors like:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/bolt-webserver/bolt/api/handlers.py", line 294, in user
mix-middleware-server    |     if not user.is_enabled:
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 287, in __get__
mix-middleware-server    |     return self.impl.get(instance_state(instance), dict_)
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 718, in get
mix-middleware-server    |     value = state._load_expired(state, passive)
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 652, in _load_expired
mix-middleware-server    |     self.manager.deferred_scalar_loader(self, toload)
mix-middleware-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 942, in load_scalar_attributes
mix-middleware-server    |     raise orm_exc.DetachedInstanceError(
mix-middleware-server    | sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <User at 0x7f9191ba28e0> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/bhk3)
```

So definitely the User object is not eagerly loaded. Any idea how I can force SQLAlchemy to completely load that object when I ask for it, and don't keep any session dependencies around?

Thanks

Comment: How are you making subsequent requests? Are you doing so in your flask app or outside your flask app?

Comment: I'm actually using tornado. And subsequent requests are done within the same framework.

Comment: But in the end it should not matter how those subsequent requests are done. What I want, is to get the DB object instance, without any DB dependencies.

Comment: Sqlalchemy works with db sessions. You can only access related objects in a particular session. If it's not available in tornado, you can scope your session so that you can still access objects and their relations in subsequent requests.

Comment: Not something I like to hear, but thanks for it!

Comment: ok. Are you using [tornado-sqlalchemy](https://tornado-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) already? Perhaps it can help

Comment: No. I use: SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
tornado==6.0.4   . Swithcing to tornado-sqlalchemy will require some substantial work, which I'm not planning to do right now.